# wxSplashScreen with transparent image

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have the following code for showing a splash screen using WxWidgets:

```cpp
wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);
wxBitmap splashBm;
if (splashBm.LoadFile(_T("splash.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG)) {
    wxSplashScreen scrn{splashBm,
        wxSPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN | wxSPLASH_TIMEOUT,
        5000, frame.get(), wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
        wxSIMPLE_BORDER | wxSTAY_ON_TOP};
    wxYield();
    //Sleep for two seconds before destroying the splash screen and showing main frame
    wxSleep(2);
    //Now destroy the splashscreen
    scrn.Destroy();
}
```

The problem is that for a PNG image with transparent background, the splash window's background will show. I'm on Linux with XFCE. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try 

`wxImage img("splash.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG); wxBitmap splashBm(img);`

?

Comment: @catalin Tried just now. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, you meant that the window behind the image was not transparent, when you painted a transparent image on it? :)

Comment: @catalin Yes, sorry for the lack of clarity. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that it is possible to set the shape of the `wxNonOwnedWindow` (which `wxSplashScreen` inherits from) with the `bool wxNonOwnedWindow::SetShape(const wxRegion & region)` method. And `wxFrame` (which inherits from `wxNonOwnedWindow`, and parent of `wxSplashScreen`) must have the style `wxFRAME_SHAPED`.

`SetShape` receives a `wxRegion` object which can be constructed from the non-transparent pixels of a bitmap.

```cpp
wxRegion::wxRegion(const wxBitmap & bmp,
                   const wxColour & transColour,
                   int tolerance = 0
                   )
```

So, we can set all the transparent pixels from an image to white, and the rest to black. Then we construct a `wxRegion` using `wxWHITE` color as the transparent color. For this I've made the following function:

```cpp
// Doesn't work well for alpha compositing
wxImage alphaToBlackAndWhiteMask (wxImage img) {

    // Some image types (e.g. gif) have a mask for the transparent pixels
    // instead of an alpha channel.
    if (!img.HasAlpha() && img.HasMask()) {
        img.InitAlpha();
    }

    if (img.HasAlpha()) {
        unsigned char *rgb = img.GetData();
        unsigned char *alpha = img.GetAlpha();

        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < img.GetWidth()*img.GetHeight()*3; x+=3, y++) {
            // If alpha pixel, make white. Else make black.
            // An alpha value of 0 corresponds to a transparent pixel (null opacity)
            // while a value of 255 means that the pixel is 100% opaque. 
            if (alpha[y] < 20) { // Using some threshold for almost transparent pixels.
                rgb[x] = 0xff;// red
                rgb[x+1] = 0xff;// green
                rgb[x+2] = 0xff;// blue
            } else {
                rgb[x] = 0x00;// red
                rgb[x+1] = 0x00;// green
                rgb[x+2] = 0x00;// blue
            }
        }

        // Remove alpha channel so that the pixels turned white will show
        img.ClearAlpha();
    }

    return img;
}
```

Then, I create the splash screen as follows:

```cpp
wxImage::AddHandler(new wxGIFHandler);

wxImage splashImg;
if (splashImg.LoadFile(_T("resources/splash.gif"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_GIF)) {

    bool hasAlpha = splashImg.HasAlpha() || splashImg.HasMask();

    wxRegion splashRgn;
    if (hasAlpha) {
        splashRgn = wxRegion(alphaToBlackAndWhiteMask(splashImg), *wxWHITE);
    }
    wxSplashScreen scrn{ splashImg,
        wxSPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN | wxSPLASH_TIMEOUT,
        5000, nullptr, -1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
        wxBORDER_NONE | wxSTAY_ON_TOP | (hasAlpha ? wxFRAME_SHAPED : 0x00) };
    if (hasAlpha) {
        scrn.SetShape(splashRgn);
    }

    // yield main loop so splash screen can show
    wxAppConsole::Yield();
    //Sleep for two seconds before destroying the splash screen and showing main frame
    wxSleep(2);
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work for alpha compositing. Meaning that we cannot have pixels with some level of transparency yet not fully transparent.

I did stumble across [this](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1471#issuecomment-571383949) solution that allows for layers with transparency by stacking them in frames and using `wxWindow`'s `virtual bool SetTransparent (wxByte alpha)` method on a frame (some systems may not support transparent windows). But as it says, alpha blending isn't really feasible because having a lot of pixels with differing transparencies would require a frame layer and image in memory for each level of alpha.

If anyone knows of a better solution that allows for alpha compositing, please let me know.